# Apache redirecting absolute url-s

Tags: apache, redirect

I want Apache to redirect links in the page site1.com/page

like a href = http://site.com/something to a href = http://site1.com/something.

It works with relative URLs using `RedirectMatch`, but not for absolute.

Redirect and RedirectMatch take relative URL for the first argument, but dont work for absolute URL as first argument.

I.e

if the host is site.com

than

```
Redirect /dir htttp://site1.com
```

redirects links a href = /dir> to site1.com

but

```
Redirect http://site.com/dir htttp://site1.com
```

does not redirect links a href = htttp://site.com/dir to htttp://site1.com

Comment: Why `RedirectMatch` and not `Redirect`? Looks like you want to redirect all called to `site.com` to `site1.com`.

Comment: @Qben It doesn seem to work for absolute URLs

Comment: @한국매미 I added them to the post.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make sure the redirect is part of `site.com`'s virtual host config, or in the htaccess file in `site.com`'s document root.
2. You can't have the hostname and scheme as part of the first parameter for a `Redirect`, only a **URL-path**.

If you want to redirect all links to another site, then you just want:

```
Redirect / http://site1.com/
```